# Why central keeps connecting/disconnecting my peripheral automatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application deivce  using TI CC254x which performs peripheral role and I'm not  far from closing my project.

Recently I found that my peripheral device is disturbed by a mobile phone.

I ported BLE-CC254x-1.4.2 in my peripheral and the Android version of my phone is 6.0.1

The test procedure  is pretty simple.

After I did connect/disconnect cycles several times from mobile phone using BLE scanner,

the central in mobile phone connects and disconnects my peripheral by itself

without any human intervention.

For that reason, other  centrals can  not make connection  to my peripheral .

(I got a failure reason of 0x3E: Failed to establish)

It looks like that there is an option in mobile phone which forces a mobile to make connection to peripheral  automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Android app has a BluetoothGatt object for the peripheral on which .disconnect() or .close() haven't been called. Otherwise it shouldn't keep the link connected (unless it's a HID device).

Comment: You mean that  BluetoothGatt.disconnect() should be called even though I want the phone to perform central role only on multi role phone, I mean which supports both roles of central and peripheral?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question here. BLE connections are reference counted. Only when all BluetoothGatt objects have been disconnected or closed (or the app holding that object is terminated), the BLE link gets disconnected.